# Angular 2 Quickstart 404 GET /app/main.js

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying the quickstart of Angular 2 but I don't get that it works. I've been finding out some similar questions but I didn´t find the answer. Anyone can help me?

This my code.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**index.html**

```
  <html>
   <head>
     <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

     <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
     <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
     <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js">   </script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
  "lite": "lite-server",
  "typings": "typings",
  "postinstall": "typings install" 
 },
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
 "systemjs": "0.19.22",
 "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
 "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
 "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
 "zone.js": "0.5.15"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
 "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
 "typescript": "^1.8.2",
 "typings":"^0.6.8"
 }
}
```

**tscoding.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6",
  "module": "system",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings/main",
  "typings/main.d.ts"
 ]
}
```

**npm start output**

```
> npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/dpcrespo/Google   Drive/projects/tutorials/angular/angular2-quickstart
> concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

[0]
[0] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 tsc:w /Users/dpcrespo/Google     Drive/projects/tutorials/angular/angular2-quickstart
[0] > tsc -w
[0]
[1]
[1] > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 lite /Users/dpcrespo/Google    Drive/projects/tutorials/angular/angular2-quickstart
[1] > lite-server
[1]
[0] Version 1.8.7
[0] Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ...]
[0]
[0] Examples: tsc hello.ts
[0]           tsc --out file.js file.ts
[0]           tsc @args.txt
[0]
[0] Options:
[0]  --allowJs                           Allow javascript files to be compiled.
[0]  --allowSyntheticDefaultImports      Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking.
[0]  --allowUnreachableCode              Do not report errors on unreachable code.
[0]  --allowUnusedLabels                 Do not report errors on unused labels.
[0]  -d, --declaration                   Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.
[0]  --experimentalDecorators            Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators.
[0]  --forceConsistentCasingInFileNames  Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file.
[0]  -h, --help                          Print this message.
[0]  --init                              Initializes a TypeScript project and creates a tsconfig.json file.
[0]  --jsx KIND                          Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve' or 'react'
[0]  --mapRoot LOCATION                  Specifies the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations.
[0]  -m KIND, --module KIND              Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd' or 'es2015'
[0]  --moduleResolution                  Specifies module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6).
[0]  --newLine NEWLINE                   Specifies the end of line sequence to be used when emitting files: 'CRLF' (dos) or 'LF' (unix).
[0]  --noEmit                            Do not emit outputs.
[0]  --noEmitOnError                     Do not emit outputs if any errors were reported.
[0]  --noFallthroughCasesInSwitch        Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement.
[0]  --noImplicitAny                     Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.
[0]  --noImplicitReturns                 Report error when not all code paths in function return a value.
[0]  --noImplicitUseStrict               Do not emit 'use strict' directives in module output.
[0]  --outDir DIRECTORY                  Redirect output structure to the directory.
[0]  --outFile FILE                      Concatenate and emit output to single file.
[0]  --preserveConstEnums                Do not erase const enum declarations in generated code.
[0]  --pretty KIND                       Stylize errors and messages using color and context. (experimental)
[0]  -p DIRECTORY, --project DIRECTORY   Compile the project in the given directory.
[0]  --reactNamespace                    Specifies the object invoked for createElement and __spread when targeting 'react' JSX emit
[0]  --removeComments                    Do not emit comments to output.
[0]  --rootDir LOCATION                  Specifies the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir.
[0]  --sourceMap                         Generates corresponding '.map' file.
[0]  --sourceRoot LOCATION               Specifies the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations.
[0]  --suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors    Suppress noImplicitAny errors for indexing objects lacking index signatures.
[0]  -t VERSION, --target VERSION        Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', or 'ES2015' (experimental)
[0]  -v, --version                       Print the compiler's version.
[0]  -w, --watch                         Watch input files.
[0]  @<file>                             Insert command line options and files from a file.
[0] npm run tsc:w exited with code 0
[1] Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
[1] ** browser-sync options **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://192.168.0.9:3000
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.0.9:3001
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./
[1] [BS] Watching files...
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /index.html
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /styles.css
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-    polyfills.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 304 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js
[1] 16.03.16 11:30:42 404 GET /app/main.js
```

**In my browser**

[image]

It's like if it doesn't transpile main.ts file to main.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `tscoding.json` a typo in the question, or is that actually what it's called in your project? Because if the latter is the case, that's your problem - it should be called `tsconfig.json`. `tsc` won't pick it up otherwise.

Comment: sorry it's typo in the question, I started new project to do the quickstart and now it's working but, I need to reload the page first, if not I get the same error 404 GET /app/main.js. it seems like doen't transpile well the main.js file. In this point I saw another question and say that it's and error and he reported to google.

Comment: same error I got it..but In my project file name are right like  tsconfig.json and main.ts but after that this app/main.js not found error is coming

Comment: Same for me using this project: https://github.com/praetorxyn/angular2-interactive-map

Answer (score 17):

I got this error as well.

In my case I had named the `tsconfig.json` wrong. When I changed to `tsconfig.json`, ran `npm install` again and then `npm start` it all worked.

Comment: Thanks man! I also wrongly named tsconfig.json as tsconfig.js :)

Comment: I am a newbie, I downloaded a demo code, deployed it into our IIS, did NPM install do download packages, then don't know what to do, tried ng build which threw an error stating the latest cli wasn't installed. I followed other answers here by changing 'app' to './app' it didn't solve. The final missing piece on my puzzle was npm start. Thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

Try changing the map in the config. In my case I have

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
    map: { 'app': './app' }
  });
```

where /app is the folder in which the components(.ts) are created

Comment: Thanks you save my day. the www.tutorialspoint.com has wrong informantion

Answer (score 8):

In your index.html is reference to app/main. Do you have your main.ts file in folder named app or in the root?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the Quickstart tutorial, and you have to change the path to main.ts in the system.config.ts =>  main: 'app/main.js'

Comment: I have the same error. In systemjs.config.js as described on [typescript tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#systemjs) there is a line `'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },` Changing this to `main.ts` did not solve this for me.

Comment: @Guus -  main: './app.main.js' fixed this for me

Answer (score 7):

`tsconfig.js` should be `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 4):

I think it was the issue with system.config section. The map value was './angular2/src/app' which is wrong. the following code fixed for me.

```
<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
    map: { 'app': './app' }
  });
  System.import('app/hello_world_main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

map: { 'app': './app' } - making sure that the components are searched under the app folder of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have globally installed **typings** and **lite-server** your cmd, type `typings`, if you don't have both installed them using `npm install -g typings lite-server`.

And add the following code to the top of **main.ts** file in **app** directory:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts" />
```

Now run `npm install && npm run`

Answer (score 2):

when command

```
npm start
```

main.ts is transpiled to .js file and word "app" is added in front of each files name.
but in the `systemjs.configs.js` it calls `main.js` not `app.main.js`

in my case, I changed

```
'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

(which is stated on angular official page / angular-2-quickstart)
to

```
'app':                        { main: 'app.main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
```

and it works well.

not sure this is best solution... (please give me feedback.)

Answer (score 2):

in your systemjs.config.js change the mapping for your app to the right path to your files, so  ... the line:

'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

change to:

'app':                        'your path here', leave blank for relative path.

Comment: Life Saver for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change  tsconfig.json to

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

then run npm install then npm start it will start working proprely

Comment: It should be tsconfig.json

Comment: No, you haven't. Your answer says ```tsconfig.js```, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a few posibilities. 
1. Do you have `main.ts` in your solution? if not create one :) 
2. If you have. It is a option, that your start project doesn't compile typescript files. So let's try the command:
`npm run tsc`
It should throw the `main.js` in typescript output folder by default it is in the same folder as `.ts` file. 
3. And last one: your start command should contains normal tsc command. It is a better to start project (in package.json) as 
`npm run tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" ...`
(this way your project doesn't run if `ts` compilation failed).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `tscoding.json` is a typo, for me it worked when I updated my `npm` and `node` to the latest versions.

The setup works fine if I have `npm` version of `3.10.3` and `node` version of `v6.5.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update your version of node and npm..

> If Node.js and npm aren't already on your machine, install them. Our examples require node v5.x.x or higher and npm 3.x.x or higher. To check which version you are using, run node -v and npm -v in a terminal window.

That is coming from the [prerequisites section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#prereq) of the quick start guide.

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
  // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
    transpiler: 'ts',
    typescriptOptions: {
      tsconfig: true
    },
    meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    },
```

on the file `systemjs.config.js` to compile the `main.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

in your tsconfig.json if you have added

```
"outDir":"yourOutDir"
```

you need to change the maping location in system.config.js

```
// our app is within the app folder
app: 'yourOutDir/app',
```

Answer (score 1):

This might seem random, but having the

```
    <base href='/'>
```

as the first tag in the `index.html` before loading any other js solved this issue

Answer (score 1):

Clearly,

update `systemjs.config.js` file

From

```
  'app': 'app',
```

To

```
  'app': './app',
```

after

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
```

...

I had the problem under windows. .

Answer (score 0):

e.x. a project folder is "tmp"

tsconfig.json changed like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir":"tmp"
  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js like this

```
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app', 


// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by removing the  "outDir": "js" in tsconfig.js file. Now all the compiled app .js files are saved to app folder instead of js folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually compiling the typescript files manually by using `tsc -p src`. Then run the dev server.

Answer (score -1):

index.html and styles.css should be in project's root folder (not app/)

Look at project structure at the bottom of [quickstart page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Answer (score -2):

Hi I had the same problem but it solve creating a folder **app** inside the root folder and move the file main.ts and app.component.ts to it [tutorial folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMJh7.png)